# Pip name conflict

Tags: python, package, pip, setup.py, pypi

My project depends on some public packages and some private ones. One of these private ones has the same name as another public package on PyPi (let's call it 'conflicting'). In my setup.py file I have

```
install_requires = ['public_a', 'public_b', 'conflicting' ],
dependency_links = ['https:blah/blah/blah/conflicting.git#egg=conflicting']
```

Even though I specify the egg in my dependency links, pip still installs the public package 'conflicting'. Is there a way to prioritize private packages when there is a name conflict?

Comment: Did you ever find a fix/workaround?

Comment: @augurar unfortunately not

Comment: If renaming the private package is not an option, you can avoid using the versions the public one uses. So if the public package has 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, your private package can go with 1.0-pro, 1.1-dev, 1.2.111. Then you explicitly set the versions in both install_requires and dependency_links. I have no idea if this works in practice.

Comment: @augurar Check out my answer below. It's a hack, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's a bit of a hack, but this is easy and it actually works:

Add 100 to your local package's version numbers. As long as pip can find your local package via the `--extra-index` or `--find-links options`, it will compare the version numbers and take the highest available version that meets the versioning constraints specified in the setup.py of the dependent package. If your package has the higher version, it will win.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up your own PyPi server and use it as primary source and the global one as secondary. This will prioritize your packages over the public ones.

e.g. manually:
`pip install --index-url=<your-pipy-server> --extra-index-url=https://pypi.python.org/simple <your package>`

Of course, errors could occur if the version you are trying to install is missing on your server but available from the conflicting public package.

Comment: If your private pypi server goes down I believe pip may (silently) install the public package